# Fullscreen minecraft with GNOME 2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, ubuntu

Every time I press <kbd>F11</kbd> to make Minecraft fullscreen in Ubuntu 10.10, the GNOME panels are ALWAYS annoying me up and down. How to get rid of them? Just clicking again on Minecraft doesn't help :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried disabling "desktop effects"? This usually works for me if I have panels showing over fullscreen applications.

This is under:

System > Preferences > Appearance > Visual Effects > None

Comment: I don't want to get off these awesome effects. Waiting for better solutions. However, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution than turning off desktop effects is to turn on "Autohide" in the panel's properties. You can reach this by right-clicking the panel.

It's not a perfect solution, but you get the full screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Don't use F11 to go fullscreen, but instead go into Minecraft settings/video and click the 'fullscreen' toggle button. This eliminated the desktop window decorations and other fluff that was bugging me.